# How can I serialize data to XML without .xsd schema?

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, serialization, xsd

I am writing an ASP.NET MVC (5) application in which I need to do some custom XML serialization. Before I go on, I should mention that I wasn't exactly sure if this question belongs here or on another forum. If this question would be better suited somewhere else, please let me know. I'll gladly move it.

**Software overview:**

I have a view that has a form for the user to fill out. When the user fills out the required fields and clicks the `submit` button, the information in the form should be serialized to XML (based on certain XML requirements), and posted to a URL. That's pretty simple for some, I'm sure. I have very little experience doing this sort of thing in ASP.NET MVC.

I don't possess the .xsd document that contains the XML schema. I have a document that contains the XML specifics (a Word document), but the actual .xsd document is not available to me. I am not sure how to serialize the data so that the XML turns out the way it is supposed to.

I have the following Model:

```
public class BookingRequest
    {
        public string billTo { get; set; }
        public string bookingStatus { get; set; }
        public string partNote { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
    }
```

Note that this is an abbreviated version; there are WAY more fields in this class. Anyway, I need the `height` field to look like this when it is serialized to XML:

```
<HeightOf>15</HeightOf>
```

I also need all of the elements in the XML to adhere to this schema (where all of the fields in the form I mentioned fall under the `<BookingRequest>` tag):

```
<Data>
    <Header>
        <UserId/>
        <Password/>
    </Header>
    <BookingRequest>
            ..
            ..
    </BookingRequest>
</Data>
```

Can I do this without the schema?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please go through this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273831/how-to-serialize-an-c-sharp-object-into-xml-without-schema-info and hope, this would be a solution.

Comment: @AT-2017 Thank you. I will gladly go through this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the xsd, as long as you know how is going to be the desired structure.
First, you need to decorate your class with the [Serializable] attribute. Then, you can use the attributes in System.Xml.Serialization namespace to control the result. For example, in case of height property, it can be achieve like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class BookingRequest
{
    public string billTo { get; set; }
    public string bookingStatus { get; set; }
    public string partNote { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "HeightOf")]
    public int height { get; set; }
}
```

See this for further details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

Comment: Very, very helpful. Thank you. +1 for now, possible answer later.